# Add ro quiet splash to all entries

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I have ubuntu and archlinux in my computer, the BOOT system (grub) is in ubuntu.
When i update grub (grub-update) the ubuntu entry gets the ro-quite-splash line. However the arch entry, after de UUID line, nothing is added automatically (Normally I edit the file grub.cfg and add it manually, which is very annoying).
I wish grub did it by himself. Sorry for the bad english ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible with normal configuration. You have to edit the scripts that are run during `grub-update`. Take a look at [this article](http://poomerang.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/dual-boot-of-linux-distros-tweaking-grub-kernel-parameters-for-the-2nd-distro/). The essentials:

- Open `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` with root rights for editing.
- Change the line `linux ${LKERNEL} ${LPARAMS}` to `linux ${LKERNEL} ${LPARAMS} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}`
- run `sudo update-grub` again

You can also use your own variable for this. For details consider the linked article.