# Can't install Ubuntu Server 18.04 but can install others fine

Tags: server, system-installation, virtualbox, 18.04

So the last 3 days I have installed Ubuntu server over and over on virtualbox getting a owncloud instance configured. worked every single time.

I then ran into an issue where all the virtual machines got deleted… it was at this moment that I could no longer install ubuntu server 18.0.4 it would get to the very end where it says installing kernel and then gives me the error “an error has occured”

Now I have since been able to install ubuntu server 16 and the ubuntu desktop 18.04 just fine. It even let me upgrade the 16 server to 18.0.4… but that takes forever to do

I also tried a different computer with virtualbox and ubuntu server 18 … I got the same error.

I tried downloading the ISO file again … same error … restarted the computer … same error … reinstalled virtualbox … same error…

I have no idea as to why this is only happening on the ubuntu 18.0.4 server on different computers now.

anyone have any ideas or having an issue installing it?

thanks!

also I looked at the syslog and  I didnt really see anything ...but then again I am not sure what I am looking for or if that was the right log to look in.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem on both, phisycal and virtual machines (VMWare). Usually the error ocurred during the "installing kernel" step.

I tried the suggestion found here https://askubuntu.com/a/1082599/212922 and it worked.

Steps

1. Start from the installation media, select languague and keyboard layout
2. Press <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>+<kbd>**F2**</kbd> to open another tty
3. Type the following and press enter

   ```
   service rsyslog stop
   ```
4. Press <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>+<kbd>**F1**</kbd> to return to the installation screen, and follow the process normaly.

Hope it works for you too.