# Source ID xxxxx was not found when attempting to remove it

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I have a new build PC.

I7-8700
Asus prime z390-a
GeForce rtx 2080
8gb ram
2tb m2
2tb hard drive (not currently connected during ubuntu install).

I'm having difficulties installing Ubuntu 18.04.
Following the solution by Daniel in the link below I have made some progress.

[Ubuntu 18.04 installation problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030103/ubuntu-18-04-installation-problem)

However I am now getting the following hundreds of errors where the XXXXX simply stands for a 5 figure number

```
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:xxx: Warning: Source ID xxxxx was not found when attempting to remove it
GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
```

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this?