# Lubuntu won't boot, stuck at initramfs

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I'm a casual Lubuntu user. I installed it a few years ago on an old laptop to keep it working. Pretty sure it was the 18.04 version.

Today, while trying to install WaterFox, I rebooted the laptop via terminal. It stopped rebooting correctly.

First of all, when I start the PC, I get

`` error: failure writing sector 0x19b802 to `hd0` ``

`Press any key to continue...`

Then, after a few seconds, I get the Lubuntu loading screen, which  brings me to

`BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.4) built-in shell (ash)`

`Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands`

I searched for solutions, tried:

`(initramfs) exit`

And got

`fsck exited with status code 12`

`The root fylesystem on /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root requires a manual fsck`

I then tried

`(initramfs) fsck dev/sda1`

And got

`fsck from util-linux 2.31.1`

I then

`(initramfs) reboot`

And I got back to

`` error: failure writing sector 0x19b802 to `hd0` ``

And the loop continues lol.
Any suggestions?

I don't care about losing the data on the PC. I just want it fixed ASAP.

The day after tomorrow I'll be able to use another PC to download Lubuntu on a pendrive (I'm typing from a phone), but if there's a way to fix it sooner please tell me.

**UPDATE**

tried

`(initramfs) fsck -py /dev/sda1`

I got the usual

`fsck from util-linux 2.31.1`

I also tried

`(initramfs) fsck.ext4 /dev/sda1`

Which gave me

`e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)`

`fsck.ext4: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sda1`

`Possibly non-existent device?`

**UPDATE #2**

I tried

`(initramfs) fsck -p /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root`

It run a few hundred lines of something and then spit out

`/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root: ********** WARNING: Fylesystem still has errors **********`

**UPDATE #3**

Any attempt to fix the filesystem through initramfs commands has yeld no results.

I found my Lubuntu 18.04 pen drive and booted the installation interface by changing the BIOS boot hierarchy. Over time I put other stuff on the pen drive, but the self-check option from the installation menu tells me that the Lubuntu copy is fine.

I managed to boot the Lubuntu trial version from the pen drive and it seems to work.

I tried to run SMART test from there. I tried both the short and the long test, they both tell me in an instant that the hard drive is ok (which raises suspicions about the test not running at all).

I tried installing Lubuntu but it freezes at a certain point of the installation. The cursor becomes a spinning wheel and it just keeps spinning. I can close the installation and keep using the trial version, but there's no way to go on with it.

I re-tried multiple times, switching my installation choices, but the outcome is always the same. I even tried to install it from the boot menu, without opening the trial version, but it's all the same.

I tried this:

[Ubuntu 18.04 installation problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030103/ubuntu-18-04-installation-problem/1133399#1133399)

up to point 5, but I still can't install it.

I need this PC to work. What's the least expensive line of action now?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137630/discussion-on-question-by-pusha-lubuntu-wont-boot-stuck-at-initramfs).

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly (ie. how important is security to you, are you offline etc?)