# Large log files followed by PCIe port Error

Tags: boot, 19.04, grub-efi, hp-pavilion

I had replaced the HDD of my HP Pavillion laptop with a 500 GB SSD with a clean install of Ubuntu 19.04 . After a day of installing important software, I get a low disk space warning, which looked to be from large log files.

I restart the laptop, but now it gets the PCIe Bus error. I tried recovery mode to delete the log files (as suggestested by [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099684) answer) but I end up with the same error unable to change anything. How should I proceed?

[image: Error]

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected  or https://askubuntu.com/questions/863150/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected-type-physical-layer-id-00e5receiver-id

Comment: @Rinzwind I did read those links, but I'm not able to enter grub or recovery mode because it directly enters this error state