# Attempting to install 18.04 leads to neverending errors

Tags: system-installation

I had a laptop running 16.04 for some time, and it served me well while traveling. I just pulled it out again after not using it for about a year, and on booting it reminded me "Hey jerk, 18.04 has come out since I last booted, time to update!" This sounded very reasonable to me and I tried to do so. The update went through the night, and stalled out somewhere along the way while installing packages. With no other options available, I made mistake #1, and killed the power.

Obviously this was the wrong choice, as I couldn't boot into the OS after doing that. No big deal, I figured, I'll just make a bootable thumb drive and install fresh. And so I did, and so I tried to do. This may or may not have been mistake #2.

Which leads us to now. Any attempt to install, either upon connecting to a wireless network or choosing to continue without connecting to one, leads directly to a never ending high speed list of what appears to be the same or very similar errors, going by too quickly to read in full, but I can catch the beginning"

"pcieport 0000:00:1c.5".

As it kindly counts the errors for me, I can see that it's counted up over 700 million in the time it took me to write this post, with no sign of stopping. I can run directly off the bootable thumb drive, so if there are any solutions available, I am all ears.

Edit1: Thanks to guiverc's suggestion to add a boot parameter, the install no longer explodes in a shower of errors. Instead though, it hangs endlessly at the sane point, or earlier. Sometimes I get as far as choosing whether or not to connect to wifi, sometimes only as far as selecting my keyboard layout. But it always hangs.

Edit2: Solution found! Although I never successfully stopped the stream of PCI-bus errors, I was able to make it through the installation by stopping the Rsyslog service before starting it. This is at best a workaround and not a proper fix, and still leaves me stuck disabling Rsyslog to prevent the billions of errors from being logged and filling my drive, but at this point, I'll take it.

Comment: Did you checksum your [18.04] ISO download? or better use the 'check disc for defects' option on the install media (thumb-drive or dvd/cd) to ensure you had a perfect download & write to media?  If you didn't do it, this would be my first step.

Comment: I did check for defects, no errors found.

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/863150/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected-type-physical-layer-id-00e5receiver-id  (ie. use what it suggests, ie. ` pcie_aspm=off ` as a boot parameter), also I found https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1798880  but it reports fixed; which 18.04 did you try to install?  18.04.3? or earlier?

Comment: 18.04.3, yeah. Adding the 'pcie_aspm=off' parameter may or may not have worked, it didn't cut to the endless screen of errors after starting the install this time... it just hasn't done anything else either since then.