# PCIe Bus Error, Physical Layer

Tags: drivers, dmesg

When I run the command `dmesg` it shows 3 times the following error:

```
[    2.725876] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[    2.725879] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[    2.725880] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:    [ 0] RxErr
```

Is this a hardware error? how do i fix it? How to know what device is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863150/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected-type-physical-layer-id-00e5receiver-id)

Answer (score 2):

You can see the device by

```
lspci -nn
```

Find the device with `[8086:9d15]`.