# How to stop Kern.log and Syslog from growing too much

Tags: drivers, 20.04

I'm running into this issue where my kern.log and syslog files get bigger every hour on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04.
It's always the same lines
I have a Wifi adapter and I can't understand what I did wrong when installing it.
There are some logs

Kern.log

```
Mar 18 07:38:46 STARSHIP kernel: [    5.645129] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
Mar 18 07:38:46 STARSHIP kernel: [    5.801212] aufs 5.x-rcN-20200622
Mar 18 07:38:46 STARSHIP kernel: [    5.833050] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
Mar 18 07:38:47 STARSHIP kernel: [    6.279906] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Mar 18 07:38:47 STARSHIP kernel: [    6.279924] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 18 07:38:47 STARSHIP kernel: [    6.279926] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:   device [8086:a295] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 18 07:38:47 STARSHIP kernel: [    6.279927] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:    [ 0] RxErr
Mar 18 07:38:47 STARSHIP kernel: [    6.279941] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Mar 18 07:38:47 STARSHIP kernel: [    6.279955] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: can't find device of ID00e5
Mar 18 07:38:47 STARSHIP kernel: [    6.279956] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Mar 18 07:38:47 STARSHIP kernel: [    6.279969] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: can't find device of ID00e5
Mar 18 07:38:47 STARSHIP kernel: [    6.279970] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Mar 18 07:38:47 STARSHIP kernel: [    6.279985] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: can't find device of ID00e5
Mar 18 07:38:47 STARSHIP kernel: [    6.279986] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
```

Syslog

```
Mar 18 07:38:54 STARSHIP kernel: [   13.164969] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Mar 18 07:38:54 STARSHIP kernel: [   13.164978] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 18 07:38:54 STARSHIP kernel: [   13.164979] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:   device [8086:a295] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 18 07:38:54 STARSHIP kernel: [   13.164980] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:    [ 0] RxErr
Mar 18 07:38:54 STARSHIP kernel: [   13.164990] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Mar 18 07:38:54 STARSHIP kernel: [   13.165041] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: can't find device of ID00e5
Mar 18 07:38:54 STARSHIP kernel: [   13.165063] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Mar 18 07:38:54 STARSHIP kernel: [   13.165069] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 18 07:38:54 STARSHIP kernel: [   13.165070] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:   device [8086:a295] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 18 07:38:54 STARSHIP kernel: [   13.165071] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:    [ 0] RxErr
```

any help to solve this problem would be very much appreciated

Comment: Did you check this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/863150

Answer (score 3):

The best option when you get error messages in your log is always to find out what the underlying problem is.

However, if everything seems to be working ok, and you still get spammed in the logs, this is the way to filter out these messages:

1. Create a new file in `/etc/rsyslog.d` (here I use the name `01-block-pcieport.conf`)

   `sudo touch /etc/rsyslog.d/01-block-pcieport.conf`
2. Enter the following into `01-block-pcieport.conf`

   `if $msg contains "pcieport 0000:00:1c.5" then { stop }`

This will filter out ALL log messages related to `pcieport 0000:00:1c.5` and you will no longer be able to troubleshoot this device using the logs.

So again, it's highly advisable to find the underlying cause before filtering out messages like this. I wonder if it may be a driver problem? I think you should investigate this first.