# Need to restart from windows to boot into Ubuntu (dual boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 in dual boot on ASUS - r541u laptop. I am never able to directly boot into ubuntu, the screen always freezes into either purple splash or plain black (not even dim light) after I log in. Previously, I was using Ubuntu 18.04 which had the same issue, but it used to crash right after the purple screen that says "ubuntu" with four dots and did not even reach the login part.

What works for me is booting into Windows and restarting the machine from the login screen. After that when I choose Ubuntu from grub menu, it successfully boots, lets me log in and works perfectly normal. This makes for a booting time of around 4-5 minutes in total. This is a really weird problem because I have no idea what changes on rebooting from Windows login screen. I have fast boot and secure boot turned off. I have tried by turning on those options too, but the problem remains the same. Please if anybody knows what is causing this issue, help me out.

**Edit**:
I also had this problem where my syslog and kernlog files in `/var/log` directory would often get extremely huge in size till they would take up all the space on the device. So I used to manaully remove those files regularly as a work around. Upon checking the logs I found that the error `pcie bus error severity=corrected type=physical layer (receiver id)` was filling them up. So I found a solution which I have posted as the answer.

Comment: Sounds like a old desktop I had years ago that would crash till the motherboard got warm. It had some kind of hardware fault could never find out what. Once warm it never had a problem.

Comment: Did you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository? Is Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   Some Slow boot settings to review if UEFI & nVidia installed. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution given here worked for me https://askubuntu.com/a/863301/988500

Basically following these steps solved the problem:

1. Create a backup of the grub configuration using
   `cp /etc/default/grub ~/grub.back`
2. Open the config file for editing
   `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
   If you have multiple ubuntu installations, edit the grub file from terminal of the installation with the issue (or use nano in root shell of recovery mode if you cannot boot into the installation)
3. Add the boot parameter `pcie_aspm=off` at the end of the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.
   The line would look like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off"`
4. After this, update the grub from the terminal or root shell of the installation that has active grub installation currently in use by the device.
   `sudo update-grub`
5. Reboot
   `sudo reboot`

This has enabled me to directly boot into ubuntu under a booting time of less than a minute. Also, the log files don't fill up the device space anymore.