# How to resolve PCIe Bus Error in Ubuntu 20.04.6

Tags: error-handling, syslog, pcie

I have installed `Ubuntu 20.04.6` on my machine and I am getting lot of below errors:

`syslog`

```
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714005] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.3
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714008] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714009] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3:   device [8086:43b3] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714010] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3:    [ 0] RxErr                 
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714061] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.3
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714065] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714065] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3:   device [8086:43b3] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714066] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3:    [ 0] RxErr                 
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714070] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.3
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714076] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714077] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3:   device [8086:43b3] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714078] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3:    [ 0] RxErr                 
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714082] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.3
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714092] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: AER: can't find device of ID00eb
    Apr 10 09:34:30 gtx kernel: [  219.714093] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.3
```

I am not sure how to resolve this. I checked online and found out that updating this parameter `pcie_aspm=off` will turn off this errors but I do not know where to apply this setting. Also not sure if this is a permanent solution or not. Can anyone please help and suggest some good working solution. Thanks

Comment: You edit Grub and ad it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863150/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected-type-physical-layer-id-00e5receiver-id)

Comment: Seems the same problem of bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2015670