# My Ubuntu is Damn Slow on a Fast Machine

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

Ubuntu version - 23.04
Laptop - HP Elitbook 840 g3
Processor - i7 6th generation
RAM - 24GB DDR4
SSD - Samsung EVO Plus 970 M.2 (500GB)

My Ubuntu is installed on the M.2 along with Windows 11. Win11 seems fast enough but Ubuntu is lagging and very slow to open even a directory, terminal, browser. What can be the cause of this issue?

I have updated from Update manager and from terminal using `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y`

Here is the output of recent journalctl entries: https://pastebin.com/4z5XwNbB

Comment: Do you have a dedicated graphics card? If so, try changing the driver in "Additional Drivers" tab in the "Software & Updates" app, and reboot.

Comment: Also, check journalctl logs with the command `journalctl -r`. Can you post them in pastebin and share the link?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi No I don't have any dedicated graphics card. journalctl -r provides hundreds of lines in output. How can I copy all of them for you? Shareing in pastebin is not a problem at all.

Comment: Try `journalctl -r > output.txt`. That would save the output to the file `output.txt`. Then, upload the contents of that file to pastebin (in case that is too large, we would need only the recent logs - let us know).

Comment: E.g., if the file is too big, to get the last 2000 lines, enter the command `journalctl -n 2000 > output.txt`. If there are any major issues, it should show up in those 2000 lines

Comment: Here you are.. https://pastebin.com/4z5XwNbB

Comment: I saw a lot of PCI bus errors. Try this https://askubuntu.com/a/1041830/124466 I don't know if it would help. Please let us know if it works

Comment: Okay I'll let you know. BTW thanks a million...

Comment: Also, some people found similar issues in 23.04 https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/141zjre/anyone_else_find_2304_slow_compared_to_2204/ Try 22.04 from a live USB, if it does not have these issues, just install it and stick to it

Comment: Hi @ArchismanPanigrahi here is the journalctl file after following the instruction from your given link. https://pastebin.com/8tt0ZCjg

Do you still see any issue?

Comment: I still see the same error. I don't know if this error causes the slowness. I don't think I can help you further in this matter. Hope someone with more experince finds this post.

Comment: I understand. You already helped me a lot. I see my Ubuntu is at least 25% faster than before. BTW what is the best place to ask question to get rid of this issue?

Comment: This is usually the best place. You can also ask at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Other things to try: Check if you have the same kind of lag in Manjaro from a live USB https://manjaro.org/. Also try Ubuntu 22.04 from a live USB