Laptop keyboard won't function after suspending
I have a Dell Vostro laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. The keyboard works fine initially but as soon as I suspend it and then turn it on, it no longer functions. I have to add an external keyboard to do my work OR restart the laptop. It is causing me a lot of trouble. It is clear that it is a software/OS related issue because it only happens on suspension. Kindly provide help.
Edit: F11 and F12 seem to be working as they are used by me as brightness decrease and increase keys.
Edit 2: Adding the specified outputs:
Before suspend:
$ sudo lsusb -tv

/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
    |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
    |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        ID 03f0:3841 HP, Inc 
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0bda:5769 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0bda:5769 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
        ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 

After suspend :
sudo lsusb -tv
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
    |__ Port 1: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
    |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        ID 03f0:3841 HP, Inc 
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0bda:5769 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0bda:5769 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
        ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 

More : https://pastebin.com/63TqhkE5
EDit : The issue got resolved on its own like rest of my issues

You'll need to add more info for anybody to be able to suggest something useful ... start by suspending your system then resume it and run journalctl --since='-2min' --no-pager (within 2 minutes) and add the output to your question ... Also the output of lsusb -tv before suspend and after resume.

Have you tried upgrading Ubuntu, e.g. fresh install Ubuntu 24.04?

@ArchismanPanigrahi No I haven't

@Raffa Output added

Exactly which Dell Vostro? inxi -S --usb? Tried a live pendrive 24.04? You can remove the lsusb -tv output after suspend since they are identical

Usually newer versions of Ubuntu have better hardware support. So, please give 24.04 a try.

Your logs show most likely ASPM related issue. See this post https://askubuntu.com/q/863150 for kernel boot parameters  that you can try and might help   … Also newer kernels as in a newer release like 24.04 suggested in the comments above might offer better support for your hardware ID 413c:2113 … Or a BIOS update might help as well if it exists and fixes that specific ASPM issue … That’s what I could spot AFAIK. I hope it helps.

This happens occasionally on my Framework 13 laptop.  In my case, a workaround is:

Switch to a text console by pressing <CTRL><ALT><F1>
Type some characters on console 1 (ie. the <F1> console) in order to confirm that the keyboard is working.
Return to the graphical desktop by pressing <ALT><F7>.

Can you confirm that you mean that your <F11> and <F12> keys (brightness) work from the resumed OS, even though you can't type characters?

Hey. Ctrl+alt+F1 just blackens the screen for two seconds then logs me out. Yeah, The brightness keys f11 and 12 are working on resumed os and no other keys work. The whole keyboard works fine on restart. The problem starts happening when I suspend my laptop and then wake it back up.

Right, I forgot that it seems you have your  through  keys configured for system functions (like brightness).  If you want to enter an actual  keystroke, you'll have to do one of two things: 1) toggle the keyboard state for the function keys using something like  (on my keyboard), or 2), hold down the  key as well, if your computer supports sending the actual keyboard function key that way.  So the modified sequence would be  .
